# What are the conditions of Iran's nuclear agreement?

Tags: iran, nuclear-weapons, nuclear-energy, jcpoa

According to the agreement between "Iran" and "China, France, Germany, the Russian Federation, the UK and the US", Iran should not be able to produce weapons of mass destruction.

But in reality the progress of Iran's nuclear program is still unknown!

(And also situation of war in the Middle East is quite uncertain.  All countries are at war with each other.)

What are the conditions of Iran's nuclear agreement?

Is it really practical agreement (or just an agreement on paper)?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific. [The JCPOA is a 16 page document](http://eeas.europa.eu/archives/docs/statements-eeas/docs/iran_agreement/iran_joint-comprehensive-plan-of-action_en.pdf). If you haven't read it yet, I would recommend that you do so and then ask any questions you have about it.

Comment: Note: agreement is not between Iran and the  Obama administration! so i edit the question.--- where in the JCPOA u see "Iran should not be able to produce weapons of mass destruction"?

Answer (score 5):

As [Philipp](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/3135/philipp) mentioned in a comment, the [Joint Comprehensive Plan of Action](http://eeas.europa.eu/archives/docs/statements-eeas/docs/iran_agreement/iran_joint-comprehensive-plan-of-action_en.pdf) is both available online and short.

The basic agreement and controls are:

- Iran agrees not to pursue nuclear weapons, but may pursue nuclear energy for other purposes.
- The International Atomic Energy Agency (IAEA) is requested to monitor and verify Iran for compliance.
- A joint commission of several countries is responsible for making sure the Plan of Action is implemented.

The basic incentives are that, once the International Atomic Energy Agency verifies compliance with the Plan's requirements, the US and European Union will cease some of their sanctions against Iran.

[Annex I](https://www.state.gov/documents/organization/245318.pdf) outlines what, specifically, Iran must do to be in compliance:

- Alter the Arak heavy water reactor to support civilian, rather than military, usage. Existing military usage will be ceased.
- The Fordow Fuel Enrichment Plans will be converted to a research center.
- Excess heavy water will be sold on the international market, not stockpiled. Iran must keep the IAEA up to date on its inventory and production of heavy water.
- For the next 15 years, Iran will not engage in re-processing any spent nuclear fuel.
- There are limits on Iran's fuel enrichment activities.

There are also provisions which require IAEA access to observe and verify Iran's compliance.