# Does Iran have any remaining obligations regarding UN Security Council resolution 2231 and testing ballistic missiles?

Tags: international-relations, united-nations, nuclear-weapons, iran

In recent US government news, Iran allegedly test-fired a missile:

> The Iranian regime has just test-fired a medium range ballistic missile that is capable of carrying multiple warheads. The missile has a range that allows it to strike parts of Europe and anywhere in the Middle East. **This test violates [UN Security Council resolution 2231](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_2231)** that bans Iran from undertaking “any activity related to ballistic missiles designed to be capable of delivering nuclear weapons, including launches using such ballistic missile technology . . .”
>   <sub>Michael R. Pompeo, Secretary of State, [State.gov](https://www.state.gov/secretary/remarks/2018/12/287722.htm)</sub>

This confuses me: the US notably pulled out of the [Iran deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action) (related questions: [1](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30848/why-did-the-usa-want-to-pull-out-of-the-nuclear-deal-with-iran), [2](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8598/why-are-some-politicians-saying-the-iran-nuclear-deal-is-bad), [3](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/18511/what-are-the-conditions-of-irans-nuclear-agreement)), which (as far as I understand) has the implications that Iran no longer has obligations not to develop nuclear weapons.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

**Question**: Does Iran have any remaining obligations regarding UN Security Council resolution 2231 and testing ballistic missiles?

Answer (score 3):

**Strictly speaking, no.**

Text of resolution is [here](http://undocs.org/S/RES/2231(2015)). Relevant part is here :

> Iran is called upon not to undertake any activity related to ballistic missiles 
>   designed  to  be capable  of  delivering  nuclear  weapons,  including  launches 
>   using  such  ballistic  missile  technology,  until  the  date  eight  years  after  the JCPOA Adoption Day or until the date on which the IAEA submits a report 
>   confirming the Broader Conclusion, whichever is earlier.

Since US effectively breached provisions of resolution, Iran is under no obligation to fulfill aforementioned obligations in it. What complicates situation even more is that all other countries, which were also under obligations by previous resolutions (mostly concerning arms sales), do not have them any more.

As with some other cases when US acted unilaterally (attack on Yugoslavia, invasion of Iraq, invasion of Afghanistan, actions in Syria etc.. ) this created major loophole in international law, allowing other countries to do the same. It is entirely clear that Russia, China and maybe even India will trade with Iran, and that Russia would certainly cooperate militarily with that country.